# Get dynamic rows of matrix based on the ones of another matrix (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, generator, octave, parity

I am new to Matlab and I need some help.
I want compute Parity Check Matrix and then to encode a codeword using Generator Matrix

My matrix is the following :

```
1 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1
```

The codeword is 1 0 1 1.

My code in Matlab is as follow :

```
printf('Generator Matrix\n');
G = [
1 0 0 0 1 1 1;
0 1 0 0 1 1 0;
0 0 1 0 1 0 1;
0 0 0 1 0 1 1
]

[k,n] = size(G)

P = G(1:k,k+1:n)

PT = P'

printf('Parity Check Matrix\n');
H = cat(2,PT,eye( n-k ))


printf('Encode the following word : \n');
D = [1 0 1 1]

C = xor( G(1,:), G(3,:) , G(4,:) )
```

My problem is that I want to get dynamically the rows of G Matrix in order to make the xor operation.
Could you help me please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this teally Matlab? Matlab doesn't have `printf`, and `xor` only takes two inputs. Anyway, maybe `C = mod(D*G,2)` does what you want (this is matrix multiplication modulo 2)

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks a lot.
I test in https://octave-online.net/ and it works!

Comment: Glad it worled! I posted it as an answer. Also, you seem to be using Octave, so I added that tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need matrix multiplication modulo 2:

```
C = mod(D*G, 2);
```

Alternatively, compute the sum of the rows of `G` indicated by `D`, modulo 2:

```
C = mod(sum(G(D==1,:), 1), 2);
```